# ¿Cómo accedo a los valores de este JSON?

Tags: python, json, bucle-for

Importo JSON y abro el archivo .json. El archivo es demasiado grande y busco las keys del mismo

```
import json

with open("PlayStoreGameAppInfoReview.json", encoding='utf8') as json_file:
    play_store = json.load(json_file)
    play_store.keys()
```

Me da como resultado esto:

```
dict_keys(['com.rockstargames.gtasa', 'com.dreamsky.DiabloLOL', 'com.fansipan.stickman.shadow.knights.fightinggames', 'com.zitga.cyberfighters.shadow.hunter.legends'...
```

Dentro de `com.rockstargames.gtasa` está esta estructura:

```
{"com.rockstargames.gtasa": {'appInfo': {'title': 'Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas',
  'description': 'Five years ago, Carl Johnson escaped from the pressures of life in Los Santos,...
```

Hago un `for` para que me recorra `com.rockstargames.gtasa` y me devuelva el valor `title` pero me devuelve TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
for result in play_store['com.rockstargames.gtasa']:
    if result["com.rockstargames.gtasa"]["appInfo"]["title"] == "Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas":
        print(f"Juego: {result['title']}")
```

Comment: `play_store["com.rockstargames.gtasa"]` es un diccionario. Al iterar por él, la variable `result` irá tomando cada una de las claves de ese diccionario. Por tanto no puedes hacer `result["com.rockstargams.gtasa"]`. No entiendo por qué valores quieres iterar...

Answer (score 1):

Corríjeme si me equivoco, pero creo que lo que tendrías que hacer es iterar el resultado del JSON directamente. Lo digo porque veo que estás haciendo una comparación en tu bucle para buscar `"Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas"`.

Lo que tendrías que hacer es:

```
import json

with open("PlayStoreGameAppInfoReview.json", encoding='utf8') as json_file:
    play_store = json.load(json_file)
    
    # Iteras cada uno para saber cuál de ellos es GTA
    for key in play_store:
        if play_store[key]['appInfo']['title'] == 'Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas':
            # Lo encontraste
            print(f'Juego: {play_store[key]['appInfo']['title']}')
```

Estoy asumiendo que cada uno de los resultados del JSON tienen la misma estructura, es decir, cada uno tiene un `appInfo`, y cada `appInfo` tiene un `title`.